# Linear representation theory of symmetric groups: $S_{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I don't really get how i do a group representations.
I know the representations of $S_{2}$ are the same of $Z_{2}$, i know, for this group that we have, the trivial and sign representations, but i don't really get how i put this on matrix form, i would be very thankfull if someone elaborate in how to make those representations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both these representations are 1 dimensional, so they're given by maps $\rho:S_{2} \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, as follows;

$\rho_{triv}(g)=1\text{, }\forall g\in S_{2}$  for the trivial representation and $\rho_{sgn}((1)(2))=1$, $\rho_{sgn}((1\quad2))=-1$ for the sign representation.

You can think of these maps as $1\times 1$ invertible matrices.

Comment: Thanks, I was using a bad notation for $S_{2}$, I have changed it to the more usual cycle notation.

Answer (score 2):

The trivial (complex) representation is the map $\phi:\Bbb Z_2\to \Bbb C^*$ that sends everything to the $(1\times1)$ matrix $1$. The sign representation is the map $\psi:\Bbb Z_2\to \Bbb C^*$ that sends $n+2\Bbb Z\mapsto (-1)^n$.

Comment: What do you mean by $n+2\Bbb Z$? Can you show me the matrix for the sign representation? I don't think i get it.

Comment: Every element of $\Bbb Z_2$ is a coset in the quotient $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$; $n+2\Bbb Z$ is the coset associated to the element $n\in\Bbb Z$.